# imbalanced dataset - class weight vs weighted loss function

Tags: neural-networks, unbalanced-classes, loss-functions, tensorflow

I'm working on a classification problem with a very imbalanced dataset. Many papers mention a "weighted cross-entropy loss function" or "focal loss with  balancing weights". I can't find any of those in tensorflow (tf.keras to be precise) but there is a `class_weight` parameter in `model.fit()`. Is there a difference between those two things or is this just the way tensorflow implements weighted loss functions?

Comment: Don't reweight at all. [Everything here and in links found there applies.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)

Answer (score 3):

The weighted cross-entropy and focal loss are not the same. By setting the `class_weight` parameter, misclassification errors w.r.t. the less frequent classes can be up-weighted in the cross-entropy loss. The focal loss is a different loss function, its implementation is available in
[tensorflow-addons](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/master/tensorflow_addons/losses/README.md).

Comment: Sorry, that maybe was a bit misleading, I know that those are different functions. My question is if the class weight parameter is just the way of passing weights to the loss function in tf.keras or if there are also special loss functions that directly take weights. And if the second case was true, wat would be the difference of those options.

Comment: Yes that's correct, in Keras you use the `class_weight` parameter, which under the hood gets converted to per-sample weights, depending on `class_weight`, which are used to compute a weighted loss across all samples.